# Prevent mandatory field asterisks labels from wrapping

Tags: html, css, forms, textfield, word-wrap

I have the following simple form with a label and field:

```
<form>
  <label for="field" class="required">
    Field label which wraps:
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="field">
</form>
```

And the following CSS:

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label.required:after {
  color: red;
  content: " *";
}
```

This makes the asterisk (*) wrap to a new line. How can I prevent this from happening, while still being able to have the label wrap on words like usual? Meaning if I add a longer field description in the label it must be able to span over 2-3 lines if needed.

See example: https://codepen.io/Yonder/pen/aKopww

[image]

Answer (score 4):

mfluehr did give me an idea for a solution. By wrapping the whole text with a span - and putting the '*' at the end using position absolute it will never wrap.

```
<form>
  <label for="field" class="required">
    <span class="text-wrapper">Field label which wraps:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="field">
</form>

<br/>

<form>
  <label for="field" class="required">
    <span class="text-wrapper">Field label which wraps over multiple 
    lines:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="field">
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label.required .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

label.required .text-wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -.7em;
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  content: " *";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is by wrapping the final word of each label in its own container.

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label.required span:after {
  color: red;
  content: "\00a0*";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="field" class="required">
    Field label which <span>wraps:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="field">
</form>

<br/>

<form>
  <label for="field" class="required">
    Field label which wraps over multiple <span>lines:</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="field">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestion! It sadly won't work for me as I won't be able to change the texts, and they'll need to be plain texts. I was thinking in the line that perhaps it's better to render the '*' in a different way, perhaps with some position absolute or similar